# How do I automatically load a tag file from a directory when changing to that directory?

Tags: vim, ctags

For each of my C++ projects I keep a tag file in the root of the source tree. How can I have Vim automatically load the tag file for that directory when I change to it?

e.g. My directory layout looks like this:

```
~/dev/project1/tags
~/dev/project2/tags
```

I start Vim (from GUI) and the present working directory defaults to $HOME. I type `:cd ~/dev/project/` and Vim should load `~/dev/project/tags`. Tomorrow I might want to work on project2, so I expect Vim to load the tags for that project when I `cd` to it.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add the following line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set tags=./tags;,tags;
```

It means "look for a `tags` file in the directory of the current file, then upward until `/` and in the working directory, then upward until `/`".

In other words, no matter where you are in your project, Vim will pick up the right `tags` for the project.

`:help tags` is a good read, it would have saved you the hassle of posting a question here.

Note: the magic part of that line is the `;` of "upward search". You can give Vim an upper limit like this: `;$HOME`.

Comment: Thank you. Vim is a great tool, but I find the built-in help completely indecipherable. Even now knowing what to look for, I can't find it.

Comment: Suppose I set `tags=tags;/usr` and the working directory is `/etc/xxx`, will Vim search upward until `/`?

Comment: Upward searching doesn't stop at all on my machine. No matter where the current directory is and what I put after the semicolon, Vim searches all the way to `/`.

Comment: `/usr` being outside of `/etc/xxx`, it is pretty normal that Vim doesn't stop before `/` since `/` is their only common ancestor. On the other hand, if you are positive upward searching never stops for you no matter what value you use then you should put together a minimum reproducible case and submit it to Vim's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try about [easytag](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags), there is an option 'g:easytags_dynamic_files' can handle it.