# Is it possible to add specific tag files to particular windows/buffers in vim?

Tags: vim, tags, ctags

Is is possible to detect keywords in the path of the **current file** open in vim and **add a particular** `tag` **file**?

My project is mainly organized in `src`, `test` and `external` blocks, but each of these blocks appear anywhere in the path, not necessarily at the beginning or at the end (otherwise [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330843/how-do-i-automatically-load-a-tag-file-from-a-directory-when-changing-to-that-di) solution could work). That is, my project has this structure:

```
feature1/src
feature1/test
feature2/src
feature2/test
external/feature3
```

I can generate a separate `tag` file for each `src`, `test` and `external` block and then detect these three keywords in the path in vim with `match(expand('%:p:h'), ...)`.

But how can I **only** load `src` tag if I am at any path containing `src`, and so forth for `test` and `external`? Command `set tags+=...` adds them for all windows (buffers) and mixing them causes many name collisions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of

```
augroup example | au!
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile */myproject/*
        \ let &l:tags = &g:tags . ',' . TagForFile(expand("<amatch>"))
augroup end
```

Where writing the function `TagForFile()` is upon you.

Comment: I tried it and works! I didn't think of `l:tags` and `g:tags`, that way each buffer keeps its own tags. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Vim already handles that scenario by way of a properly set `&tags` option:

```
set tags=./tags;
```

The value above tells Vim to look for a `tags` file:

- in the directory of the current file, with `./tags`,
- recursively, up to the root of your file system, with `;` (see `:help 'tags'` for limiting).

In this case…

- with the value above and while editing `feature1/src/dir/file.c`, Vim is going to look for a `tags` file at the following locations, in order:

  ```
  feature1/src/dir/tags
  feature1/src/tags
  feature1/tags
  ...
  ```
- with the value above and while editing `external/feature3/file.c`, Vim is going to look for a `tags` file at the following locations, in order:

  ```
  external/feature3/tags
  external/tags
  ...
  ```

Comment: Using the built-in downwards recursive search I would need to populate all folders with a `.tags` file containing *all* the tags of that block. For example, both  `feature1/src` and `feature2/src` need the same `.tags` file with the information of all `src` folders, because it is possible to jump to definitions anywhere in the project. I can only think of creating soft links to a central file, but this is not manageable.